# Get interval between 2 operations using ctime?

Tags: c, ctime

I am interested in showing the execution time for a program in C, at diverse points, using ctime. 
I have tried something like that, but it must not be right...

```
int main() {

    time_t tm1, tm2;
    tm1 = time(NULL);
    sleep(2);
    tm2 = ctime(tm1);

    printf("%d\n", tm2-tm1);
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion or a proper example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on in what granulity you want to get result. If seconds so its ok to get time in the beginning and in the end of main via `time()`.

Comment: yes, preferably in seconds! but my code is not functional :(

Comment: You shoud take `time(NULL)` in both cases. It returns current time.

Comment: thank you all . now it's clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctime()` returns a string representation of the time passed into it.

If you want a simple elapsed time, just:

```
    time_t t1, t2;
    t1 = time(0);
    sleep(2);
    t2 = time(0);

    printf("Elapsed: %d\n", t2 - t1);
```

See `man ctime` and `man 2 time`.

Comment: `difftime(t2, t1)` (which is a `double`) is the portable way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `time` function to get the current time and the `difftime` function to compute the difference, in seconds, between two times (error handling omitted):

```
time_t t0, t1;
t0 = time(NULL);
foo();
t1 = time(NULL);
printf("foo() took %f seconds.\n", difftime(t1, t0));
```

However, `time_t` is intended for measuring calendar times. The `time` function typically has a one-second interval. If this is too coarse, you can try using `clock_t` and the `clock` function (error handling omitted again):

```
clock_t t0, t1;
t0 = clock();
foo();
t1 = clock();
printf("foo() took %f seconds.\n", (double)((t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
```